# Java & Docker app can not hit external API

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, feign

I have a problem connecting to an external API from a Java application built using Spring boot and feign.
The application is deployed to a VM in a docker container.
I'm trying to hit an external service endpoint to retrieve some data with no luck so far.

I have executed the same command with curl both from the VM command line and from inside the docker container also from command line but when trying to hit it from the java code I just receive a timeout.

Any ideas about what can be happening, apparently the hosts file and proxy are correct giventhat I can hit the endpoint via curl, so I guess I'm missing something in the code itself or the setup for java.

```
@GetMapping(value = "${url}", headers = {
            "X-API-Key=${apiKey}",
            "Authorization=${authorization}",
            "Accept=application/json",
            "Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8"
    })
    CheckResponse checkEmail(@RequestParam("email") String email) throws FeignClientException;
```

The curl request that works from the docker and VM.

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://${url}/emailcheck-e?email=test@email.com' --header 'X-API-Key: ${apiKey}' --header 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: ${Authorization}'
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the root cause, but in the `curl`-command you use `--header 'Authorization: ${Authorization}'`  while in the `@GetMapping` you use `"Authorization=${authorization}"`.

Comment: Also, I fail to see where the `emailcheck-e`-part of the path is defined in the `@GetMapping`.

Comment: The "=" is the way to map headers for feign. The emailcheck part is encoded as part of the URl in the java code. When I make the changes to hide the real URL I made a mistake and use the same ${url} with different scope, in the real code the "https://${url}/emailcheck-e" it is the same as the "value = ${url}" in the java code.

Comment: The point with the headers was aimed at case-sensitivity (`${Authorization}` vs. `${authorization}`)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it that way. Anyway, that difference in casing was added by me when modifying to call to hide the data. Both of them are populated with the same Authorization info.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be in the connection to the external API from a vm. When you start a DockerContainer you can specify the ports beeing map to from the vm to your localmachine using the `-p` Parameter. For detailed information you may wanna check the docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/port/

Comment: We are currently mapping the 8081 -> 8080 I don't know if we are missing one but if that's the case. Shouldn't it fail to reach the endpoint from the docker container using curl as well? It should go the same route...

Answer (score 0):

We managed to fix it by adding the proxy server config to the feign config.
Apparently even when the proxy was set to work for the VM & the docker container the java code needed it explicitly.